# How to get record type field's ID and name?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Is it possible to get record type's all the fields ID and name using Suitescript 2?

Example,
I am creating the custom record type in NetSuite there is a custom field which will have  value as Customer once the the record saved need to fetch all the customer record fields and their names using Suitescript.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, it's possible. Can't provide a link, since I'm using a PDF file, just look into the 'N/record' module. The module api itself, and the record.Record object, name spaced under the 'N/record' module.

Here is an example in a client script, which you can try in a web browser's console (with an appropriate id substitution, of course):

```
require(['N/record',], (nRecord) => {
  const so = nRecord.load({
    type: nRecord.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    id: 12210,
  });
  const f = so.getFields();
  console.log(f);
});
```

The value of the f variable will be an array of all fields on this record type.

[image: an example run on a NetSuite page]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a UserEvent Script. As you need to fetch the Customer details before the record is submitted, you can use BeforeSubmit Entrypoint in UserEvent.

To fetch all the details, you can load the record in the beforeSubmit function.

```
let customerRecord = record.load({
   type:record.Type.CUSTOMER,
   id: (You can obtain it from your current Custom Record using getValue)
});
```

Once loaded, you can simply do a customerRecord.getValue() to fetch all the desired values from the Customer Record.

If you are going to populate the currently fetched customer details on your custom record, don't forget to save the record.

Let me know if you have any questions in the comments.